# Firebase reading shortlink in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, android-deep-link

I am unable to read the shortlink from FirebaseDynamiclink.
Is there any inbuild method from FirebaseDynamiclink available.
Is there any workaround available.

This is my sample Deeplink: https://kuralprod.test.com/abouthelp.

This is my sample short link: https://kural.test.com/about

NOTE- This short link is created from Firebaseconsole not from mobile app client.

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(getIntent()).addOnSuccessListener(pendingDynamicLinkData -> {
            // is it possible to read the short link here
           // I need to read this URL [https://kural.test.com/about]
        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            
});
```